# Insert row based on value in ActiveX combobox

Tags: vba, excel

In column B, I have a list of company's. I have a combobox called ComboBox1 at the top of the sheet and also a button called InsertContact1. The combobox pulls all the company's from column B and what I want to do is if the user selects *Company D* from the drop down and hits the insert contact button, it will find the company in column B and insert a row below - which will allow the user to enter a contact for that company in another column (manually at the moment).

Here is my code so far... I'm not too sure where I am going wrong but I am getting an error that says "Argument is not optional".

This is the code I have so far in Sheet1 (Database):

```
Public Function ContactAdd(SearchedCompany As String) As Long
Dim cF As Range

With Worksheets("Database").Range("B:B")
Set cF = .Find(What:=Worksheets("Database").ComboBox1, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If Not cF Is Nothing Then
    cF.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    ContactAdd = cF.Offset(1, 0).Row
    Exit Function
End If
End With

ContactAdd = 0
End Function

Private Sub InsertContact1_Click()
ContactAdd
End Sub
```

The private sub is for the button to call the function, however this is what keeps getting an error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to pass an argument to the ContactAdd function. Like ContactAdd( "somecompany")

Comment: Oh excellent, I didn't realise this. It works when I just use any text... what does this do?

Comment: The way it works is that your ContactAdd Function takes the SearchedCompany argument as a string. At the moment you aren't using that string for anything, so you could just remove the argument from the function, and then call the function without any argument.

Comment: Right, got it. Thank you!

Comment: If you supply your response as an answer, I can mark this question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment your ContactAdd function takes a string argument, and you are calling it without passing a string.

Since you are not using the string argument of the function, you can remove the SearchedCompany Argument from the function definition, and call it like you do at the moment:

```
Public Function ContactAdd() As Long
```

Otherwise you can pass an argument when you call the function:

```
Private Sub InsertContact1_Click()

    ContactAdd ("some string")

End Sub
```